# Titanium.Facebook getting graph api access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, appcelerator

I'm developing an iPhone app with Appcelerator Titanium `SDK 1.6.2`

I am upload an photo to a users facebook album with the Titanium Facebook module, graph api.

The upload goes just fine and returns the items unique ID.

When I try to parse the JSON from the unique id I'm told i need to pass an access token, which makes sense.

How do I get the access token to be passed to the graph request url?

When I do a XHR GET request while passing Ti.Facebook.accessToken I get the following error

```
URL: https://graph.facebook.com/10150527948301195?access_token=t4CqzHallahfy4d7RnERrJb4ffOkQfJvrYrGEBoZ4so.epdiI6IjJGR2ZFY1ZTMHh6RlR6ZmNIcVctMHcifQ.NBRMth0vb7pXKcd8lHNz9aremoyNpvrbhz2P3zkgWJU4eHdfewOp1WruBNZS_lSDy0XM0Xu0ACry8aEmSckGJVQJxEioykrNZhT7S9mJG2OKWqMdk6ucg5IMhXMfndF9sdKwWrWb7uPKI57LzIOf5lvA

{
    error = {
        message = "Unsupported post request.";
        type = GraphMethodException;
    };
}
```

And if I don't pass Ti.Facebook.accessToken I'm asked for it.

I'm bound to be missing something, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

see this link http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/02/facebook-module-changes-in-titanium-mobile-1-6-0.html

I think you should be using `Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath(...)`

Comment: I'm using requestWithGraphPath to post the photo but the photo's details reside at `https://graph.facebook.com/10150527948301195`... I'm not sure what the request url for the module would be...

Comment: when I use Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('10150527948301195') I get the following error: `The operation couldn't be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)`